# How does one turn on Hyperthreading?

Tags: kernel

So I've been trying to enable hyperthreading to no success.
I have dual [Xeon E5-2690](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/64596/intel-xeon-processor-e52690-20m-cache-2-90-ghz-8-00-gts-intel-qpi/specifications.html) and hyperthreading doesn't seem to work.

lscpu output

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              8
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           45
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 0 @ 2.90GHz
Stepping:                        7
CPU MHz:                         2893.138
CPU max MHz:                     3800.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1200.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5786.28
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       512 KiB
L1i cache:                       512 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        40 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-15
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT disabled
Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon p
                                 ebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_d
                                 eadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
```

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-128-generic root=UUID=f2b4ef72-029f-4963-a60f-676ce0a33ce3 ro maybe-ubiquity acpi=off apm=off maxcpus=32
```

grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/*

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/active:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/control:on
```

OS Ubuntu 20.04.5, Kernel 5.4.0-128-generic.
Hyperthreading works on Windows, but I would rather not use Windows.
Hyperthreading is enabled on BIOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the actual output from `lscpu`. Add the contents of `cat /proc/cmdline` to your question. If hyperthreading is enabled in BIOS it should be enabled used in Ubuntu by default. Also show us `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/smt/*`

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Your kernel command line has `acpi=off apm=off`. If I add those to my grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then I lose SMT (hyperthreading) along with most CPUs. Could you edit your question with reasons for those entries and/or delete them, at least as a test.

Comment: Thank you so much this was it. I can't remember why I had them. I guess I'll remember when something breaks!